# Does anyone know how to answer this stats q.?

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with $E(Y) = 3$, $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = 4$, $E(X) = 5$, $\operatorname{Var}(X) = 6$, and $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y) = 0$. Suppose we do a linear regression of $X$ on $Y$, which gives us the resulting linear model:

$Y = a + b X.$

What are the values of $a$ and $b$?

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer this question without additional information since it's possible that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. If we assume they are gaussian then we can say that they are independent and that the population parameters would be $a=3$ and $b = 0$ since that yields the estimator with the lowest mean square error.